# red spots on the chicken

Tags: food-safety, chicken

[image]

Are those red spots on the chicken ok? or does it mean chicken has got some bacteria or it is not fresh?

Comment: Judging from the picture alone, I'd say this is perfectly fine. Do you have additional information that might be worrying?

Comment: It looks like blood spots to me (almost a bruise), not bacteria.

Comment: Did you wash the chicken before taking a picture? Maybe it is just a blood, washing it a little will remove that one. Don't thoroughly wash it as it may remove the chicken flavor.

Comment: Please **PLEASE** don't wash your chicken. You're more likely to get sick from washing chicken than you would from eating 7 day old left overs.. https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=dont+wash+chicken

Comment: Oh and definitely just a bit of blood. It'll be fine once cooked.

Answer (score 1):

They are little blood spots, perfectly safe to eat but often a sign of cheap and/or poor welfare birds. As long as you cook it properly (take it to at least 140f) its fine to eat.