# Chicken or quail have black or dark red spots on the meat

Tags: chicken, raw-meat

Is this normal?

I've got about 10 quail meats and some of them have these spots.

Are these safe to cook and eat? Is it possible that they had a disease or were infected?

I'm scared of Coronavirus, and chickens and quails can carry influenza and Coronavirus is a type of influenza, so could this be related?

[image: quail]

I've googled a lot but I can't find anything on it:
"Quail red OR black OR dark spot on meat"
etc.

My question is not a duplicate of: [red spots on the chicken](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/50269/red-spots-on-the-chicken)

Comment: Coronavirus is not a foodborne disease. You don't need to fear your food.

Comment: They do believe that it initially infected humans through meat from a "wet" market, where fresh meat is sold near the living animals. That's not the primary or most worrisome means of transmission, but worth acknowledging.

Comment: Coronavirus is not a type of influenza, these are different categories of virus although the symptoms of infection are similar. Poultry can contract a specific kind of influenza that in rare cases can transmit to humans ("Bird Flu"). The exact origin of the current coronavirus outbreak is currently *unknown* - a market in Wuhan is suspected but some reports indicate there were early infections with no connection to the market.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's just clotted blood.

Quail is a far more game-y meat than chicken meaning there is much more muscle and you end up with a lot of dark meat. You get the same with truly free range chickens.

This is nothing to worry about and I have never seen a quail which doesn't look like that.

Source: My mum had a poultry farm.

Comment: Yep. I have friends who hunt. It seems all game birds have that too.